# Show elements of array in button text in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I'm saving the textfields data in SQLite when click the save button. Now I want to show that data in button text. I'm getting data from SQLite in an `NSMutableArray`,  but when I set the `titleLabel` of button it does not appear there. How can I get the array data in button text. My code to get data from SQLite is this:

```
- (IBAction)btnShow:(id)sender {

    NSString *show=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"select * from persondata where id='%@'",_txtID.text];

    dboperation *db = [[dboperation alloc]init];
    _arrmainData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    _arrmainData=[db getalluser:show];

    NSLog(@"Arr %@",_arrmainData);

    for (NSDictionary * oneCustomer in _arrmainData){
        [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"address"];
        NSLog(@"ID: %@ ",oneCustomer);
        _btnShowData.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",oneCustomer];
        NSLog(@"XX %@",_btnShowData.titleLabel.text);
    }
}
```

Comment: `it does not appear there.` what do you have exactly? From you code, I'd say that you have a `{` appearing, that's all, or nothing (`NSLog(@"ID: %@ ",oneCustomer); prints `nil`)`. Also your code have some issue. The alloc/init of `_arrmainData`. `dboperation` is a new object, is that normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the title like this

```
  [_btnShowData setTitle: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"address"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: both are assign whats the difference in your answer

Comment: Bro i get array like this Arr (
        {
        address = Centaurus;
        city = Islamabad;
        contact = 456;
        country = Pakistan;
        id = 2;
        name = Muzzamil;
    }
)
2017-11-13 15:16:5 from sqlite , how can i get name or address in button text? @Waqas Sultan

Comment: for setting address value as title [_btnShowData setTitle: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"address"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

for name 
 for setting address value as title [_btnShowData setTitle: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"name"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
_btnShowData.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",oneCustomer];
```

with

```
[_btnShowData setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",oneCustomer] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: both are assign whats the difference in your answer

Comment: Bro i get array like this Arr ( { address = Centaurus; city = Islamabad; contact = 456; country = Pakistan; id = 2; name = Muzzamil; } ) 2017-11-13 15:16:5 from sqlite , how can i get name or address in button text? @ThreeCoins

Comment: Bro i get array like this Arr ( { address = Centaurus; city = Islamabad; contact = 456; country = Pakistan; id = 2; name = Muzzamil; } ) 2017-11-13 15:16:5 from sqlite , how can i get name or address in button text? @Priya

Comment: `[_btnShowData setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[oneCustomer objectForKey:@"address"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`